# Unexpected Behaviour with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, future, completable-future

I am trying to create a simple example with async CompletableFuture's but I'm seeing some weird behaviour. The idea is that I kick off 2 async futures, one activates a boolean flag after a set time and the other polls that flag to release the value once thread 1 has changed that flag. Here's my code:

```
package completablefutures;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class CFMain throws InterruptedException {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CF cf = new CF();
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(cf::getCompletable).thenRun(() -> System.out.println("Post-future action"));
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(cf::doSleep);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

And the CF class:

```
package completablefutures;

public class CF {
    private boolean valueIsSafe = false;

    public boolean getCompletable() {
        System.out.println("Fetching completable");
        while(true) {
            if(this.valueIsSafe) {
                System.out.println("Completable fetched");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean doSleep() {
        System.out.println("Started sleeping");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.valueIsSafe = true;
        System.out.println("Finished sleeping");
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I let the program run it's course, it prints this:

> Fetching completable
>
> Started sleeping
>
> Finished sleeping
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

i.e. the future never completes in the 10s allocated. So what's going on here?

Comment: First though would be to set the `valueIsSafe` as `volatile` since it's accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: ah yes, you're right. can't believe i missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the `valueIsSafe` from multiple threads, you must define this variable as `volatile`.

```
private volatile boolean valueIsSafe = false;
```

Using the volatile keyword will prevent threads from caching this value and force them to read the raw memory on every access.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not using a thread safe data type, you can change your code to use AtomicBoolean here is an example of your code using AtomicBoolean:

```
public class CF {
    private AtomicBoolean  valueIsSafe = new AtomicBoolean (false);

     public boolean getCompletable() {
            System.out.println("Fetching completable");
            while(true) {
                if(this.valueIsSafe.get()) {
                    System.out.println("Completable fetched");
                    return true;
                }
                //System.out.println("doing something");
            }
        }

        public boolean doSleep() {
            System.out.println("Started sleeping");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.valueIsSafe.set(true);
            System.out.println("Finished sleeping");
            return true;
        }
    }
```